# How can I embed a custom ROLLING date range in a Google Ads API Query?

Tags: google-ads-api

I am utilizing the Google ads API to pull campaign data and I am having an issue where I would like to use a fixed date range in my query, but it seems to be unavailable as an option in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/query/date-ranges#custom_date_range).

Here is my query:

```
GAquery = """
SELECT
    segments.date,
    segments.device,
    campaign.name,
    metrics.clicks,
    metrics.conversions,
    metrics.conversions_value,
    metrics.cost_micros,
    metrics.impressions
FROM
   campaign WHERE segments.date DURING LAST_30_DAYS
ORDER BY
    metrics.clicks DESC"""

# Issues a search request using streaming.
response = ga_service.search_stream(customer_id=customer_id, query=GAquery)
```

I am looking to get the LAST_60_DAYS instead of 30, but changing the LAST_30_DAYS to LAST_60_DAYS errors out. Has anyone found a way to code a rolling date range that is not a preset option in the system or are we stuck with only the preset options?

Thanks so much for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

The predefined date ranges you linked to are the only ones that exist.

If you need a different time range than the available options, you're going to have to calculate the start and end dates yourself and use a custom date range with `segments.date BETWEEN '<START_DATE>' AND '<END_DATE>'`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create the variable names yourself and insert them into the query.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
sixty_days_ago = datetime.now().date() + timedelta(days=60)
now = datetime.now().date()
```

Then in your query:

```
GAquery = f"""
SELECT
    segments.date,
    segments.device,
    campaign.name,
    metrics.clicks,
    metrics.conversions,
    metrics.conversions_value,
    metrics.cost_micros,
    metrics.impressions
FROM
   campaign WHERE segments.date BETWEEN {sixty_days_ago} AND {now}
ORDER BY
    metrics.clicks DESC"""
```